# Primitive vectors in $A^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with 1. Let n be a positive integer. I call a vector $(a_1,...,a_n) \in A^n$ primitive, if the ideal generated by $\{a_1,....,a_n\}$ is $A$.

Question: Given a primitive vector $v$, can we always find a basis of $A^n$ containing $v$? Or put in another way: is it true that $GL_n(A)$ acts transitively on primitive vectors?

Comment: Yes for PID i know how to prove it. Thanks for the reference to Hermite rings!

Comment: What you call `primitive vector' is usually called a `unimodular row'. There are many important cases where what you ask is true. Probably, the most important case is a polynomial ring (in finitely many variables) over a PID, known as Quillen-Suslin Theorem.

Comment: Thanks for the terminology correction, and for the reference to this(pretty non-trivial!)theorem

Comment: One more comment. If $(a_0,\ldots,a_n)$ is a unimodular vector, it is clear that so is $(a_0^{r_0},\ldots, a_n^{r_n})$ for any non-negative integers $r_i$. Suslin showed that these form the first row of a non-singular matrix if $n!$ divides $\prod r_i$. The necessity of this condition in general follows from Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch theorem without denominators.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very interesting remark